# main.jsbundle, Foundation and Security missing in the project, causing error

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I've noticed that file `main.jsbundle` file is missing from the project and am not sure of how to fix it, should I delete the file / is there a step I can perform to fix it?

Here is a screenshot of where it is in the project:

[image]

**Update:**

Similar issue appears with following frameworks as well

[image]

Comment: try the following *command* in the root of your project `$ react-native bundle --minify` to re-generate the offline bundle

Comment: @pritishvaidya this error output occurs `error: unknown option `--minify'` using react-native-cli v2.0.1 with react-native v0.39.2

Comment: i think they removed the minify option in some of the latest version,you can try this command `$ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle` from the root of your project

Comment: @pritishvaidya this seems to have worked, with one error outputted `Assets destination folder is not set, skipping...` any ideas? Also, would you like to submit a more detailed answer for this so I can reward a bounty?

Comment: for this error i want to know the version of your `react-native`

Comment: @pritishvaidya 0.39 for the lib and 2.0.1 for cli

Comment: ok i think i'll update it with my answer tomorrow,thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem can be resolved as follows

- By using the `react native` command line
- `$ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle` using this in the *root of the react native project*
- When the `main.jsbundle` file is generated add it back to the `Add Files to Project` option
- Just verify that the file is included in the *build phase* and `re-build`

**Update**
For the asset destination to be set *they have to be in same folder*.

Try this,it would create the asset folder

```
$ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're ejecting from `create-react-native-app` on react-native v0.50+ the `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` files are now combined into `index.js`

Before or after ejecting run

`npm i -g react-native-cli` if you `npm install`

or

`yarn global add react-native-cli` if you `yarn install`

...After Ejecting...

[bad advice]run `react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle` .  <-- Do Not do this.

[*UPDATE*] The main.jsbundle is created when xcode opens the terminal bundler. make sure you don't close the terminal window and it will run fine.

Comment: Don't think this is the issue, I never created app with `create-react-native-app` it was done via cli normally. Node modules have been deleted alongside package-lock file, even reset npm cache and re-installed them, so don't think issue is there either :/

Comment: Yeah, this question already had a correct answer, I stumbled upon it and just left this answer for people using CRNA because I had the same issue for a little bit.

Comment: Even further update. You do not need your main.jsbundle file. All you need is to make sure that xcode runs the jspackager in a terminal window. Do not close that window and it will serve the main.jsBundle during archiving. It's that same window that opens up when running simulator.

Comment: @myself I'm bundling for bugsnag inside of a separate folder to keep it clean with the map & meta. Is there a way to change to reference that bundle instead of the default do you know?

Comment: @myself if previously i tried to BAD advice -i dont remember from where but i remember i did that, how can i correct that mistake, thanks

Answer (score 6):

i am using **react-native version- 0.47.1**
in my case after running the command suggested by **@pritishvaidya** solved the main.js bundle issue, but even in release build i could see the yellow warning boxes.
So i modified the command by adding **--dev false**. That did the trick.
Leaving this updated command here in case, someone is stuck like me.

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a mac. I'm new to react native, I had the same issue. After 2 hours of trying everything suggested, I solved it. I realised that you need to first start it on a different tab inside the terminal and then run the command `"react-native run-ios"`. So if you still have problems, open terminal, have 2 tabs open. 
1) First cd to your project and enter `"npm run start"`. 
2) Then go the second tab and enter `"react-native run-ios"`. That should do it.

If you have problems with `"react-native run-android"` then you should have its simulator open beforehand. Open a third tab and go to `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools`, then enter  `"./emulator -list-avds"` to see your installed android simulators, then start one with `"./emulator -avd {your-emulator-name}"`. When you are done, hit `"react-native run-android"`.