# React-Native iOS project not building anymore

Tags: node.js, xcode, macos, react-native, fastlane

I created a React-Native app and everything worked fine till I reinstalled Nodejs on my Mac.

NodeJS version: 8.9.3

Yarn version: 1.3.2

Fastlane version: 2.70.2

Now I get these errors:

```
...
▸ Linking myapp
⚠️  ld: object file (/Users/kay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-fzwplvzpqltyirhkflrgkwgrvkqi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNSound.a(RNSound.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)
▸ Linking myapp
⚠️  ld: object file (/Users/kay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-fzwplvzpqltyirhkflrgkwgrvkqi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNSound.a(RNSound.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)
...

❌  error: No such file or directory (os error 2)

❌  error: File /Users/kay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-fzwplvzpqltyirhkflrgkwgrvkqi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/kay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-fzwplvzpqltyirhkflrgkwgrvkqi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/myapp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
(1 failure)
[23:27:08]: Exit status: 65

+---------------+-------------------------+
|            Build environment            |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.70.2                  |
| export_method | ad-hoc                  |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS11.2.sdk        |
+---------------+-------------------------+

[23:27:08]: ▸ + echo 'error: File /Users/kay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-fzwplvzpqltyirhkflrgkwgrvkqi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with'
[23:27:08]: ▸ error: File /Users/kay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-fzwplvzpqltyirhkflrgkwgrvkqi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
[23:27:08]: ▸ + echo 'React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues'
[23:27:08]: ▸ React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
[23:27:08]: ▸ + exit 2
```

Comment: It sais your `main.jsbundle`  does not exist in that directory. Where is it?

Comment: I have no idea. Normally this build process starts the bundler that creates it, I guess? The bundler terminal opens, but I still get this error. I also tried to bundle "manually" via `react-native bundle ...`  but then I got an error about an unresovlable module `AccessibilityInfo`

Comment: I might be your code signing is not set up correctly. Can you check building from the command line with` xcodebuild` directly, or creating an archive in Xcode?

Comment: There is a related Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444682/875725). Maybe that helps.